Android Java toolbar get icon click from individual fragments
I have a Bottom Navigation Toolbar and a Toolbar in my MainActivity, I also have a FrameLayout that switches from one Fragment to another. This is my MainActivity Layout:
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
        
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" >
        
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        
                        >
                    </ImageView>
        
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="PollIt"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/login_logo_font"
                        >
        
                    </TextView>
        
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/refreshData"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                        >
                    </ImageView>
        
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        
        
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
                android:text="Fragment"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
        
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

So in the toolbar I have an ImageView with the id "refreshData", if I'm in Fragment 2, how do I get the click event when I click "refreshData" so that I can refresh the data within different Fragments?
Update

I tried what was suggested, set this code in onCreateView():
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    main.imageRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Follow News", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    });

But the click wont fire.
I put the debugger on and the breakpoint is hitting but the Toast Message never appears, not sure but maybe this is another question.

Its not easy but we can achive by a trick, also note that it will be memory sensitive.
first in your mainActivity create a public static variavle for the ImageView with the id "refreshData".
val refrishView = finViewById(R.Id.refreshData);

initialize it in main activity.
now the trick is In the fargment/framelayout class access the variable by
Mainactivity.yourVariable.setOnclickListner();

thats it. Let me know if you dont understand/

I have tried this:
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
main.imageRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Follow News", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    });

but wont fire the onclick

I have added the public variable for the refresh reference but cant seem to fire the event in the fragments

Is it working? If not then access like Mainactivity.imageRefrish.setonClikListner

It's working thanks, @Somnath Nath

You are most welcome
